# Diagram of Stack Exchange database

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I want to know how these famous sites normalize their databases.

Can any one share the pictorial representation of Stack Exchange or Overflow?

Comment: You can get some insight about the database schema using the [SE Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1863/179541.

Comment: Here is [the database schema description of what is public available](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

Comment: @rene in this link. Users table does not contain any user image info then where stack dba saving it.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you ask but if it is about the user profileimage then those are stored off-site, the [usertable only holds the url to the image](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/281441). When no image is provided a default one is generated based on your emailadres.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The software of Stack Exchange is closed source so only a Stack Exchange employee has that answer.

There is however a [public available database dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) and The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com). The last one can be visual represented as follows:

> [image: ERD SEDE]

<sup>click image for larger version</sup>

Visit [my MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250439/158100) to learn how this diagram was created.

Comment: this only contains public data which is open for all and even does not have email and password attribute in user table.

Comment: @Kartik_Agarwal Which is exactly the data that SE will not expose, so this is about as good as you're going to get.

Comment: I am making a little bit similar web application as my final project. so i wanted database in best normal form like real applcaions